# Matplotlib stacked plot with uneven data

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, histogram, stacked

I'd like to plot a stacked histogram plot, but I have data columns of uneven size, and indeed data type:

```
bovine_eta = bovine['Emissivity'].dropna()
equine_eta = equine['Emissivity'].dropna()
ovine_eta =  ovine['Emissivity'].dropna()

bovine_eta.sort()
equine_eta.sort()
ovine_eta.sort()


print(bovine_eta)
['0.93' '0.93' '0.93' '0.95' '0.95' '0.95' '0.95' '0.95' '0.95' '0.95' 
 '0.95' '0.95' '0.95' '0.95' '0.95' '0.95' '0.96' '0.96' '0.97' '0.97'
 '0.97' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98'
 '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98'
 '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98'
 '0.98' '0.985' '0.985' '0.985' '1']

print(equine_eta)
['0.95' '0.95' '0.95' '0.96' '0.97' '0.97' '0.97' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98', '0.98' '0.99' '0.99']

print(ovine_eta)
['0.95' '0.97' '0.97-0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98' '0.98', '0.98' '0.98']
```

I then try

```
plt.hist([bovine_eta, equine_eta, ovine_eta], stacked=True)
```

and get the resulting plot:
[image]
This seems very weird, but obviously not far off from what I'd like actually want. How do you fix the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that all values are strings. For a histogram it helps to convert them to floats. A next problem is that the third entry of `ovine` is a string that can't be converted to a float. `'0.97-0.98'` could be replaced by an intermediate value.

As the data is almost discrete, it helps to explicitly provide bin edges aligned with these values.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bovine_eta = ['0.93','0.93','0.93','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.95','0.96','0.96','0.97','0.97','0.97','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.985','0.985','0.985','1']
equine_eta = ['0.95','0.95','0.95','0.96','0.97','0.97','0.97','0.98','0.98','0.98', '0.98','0.99','0.99']
ovine_eta = ['0.95','0.97','0.97-0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98','0.98']

ovine_eta[2] = '0.975'  # '0.97-0.98' isn't a valid number

bovine_eta = np.array(bovine_eta, dtype=float)
equine_eta = np.array(equine_eta, dtype=float)
ovine_eta = np.array(ovine_eta, dtype=float)

plt.hist([bovine_eta, equine_eta, ovine_eta],
         bins=np.arange(0.93, 1.01, 0.01),
         stacked=True, label=['bovine', 'equine', 'ovine'])
plt.legend()
```

[image: stacked bars]